# How do I send invitations to a family calendar from Outlook?

Tags: calendar, family-sharing

I am struggling to arrange work-family life, and a shared calendar seems to be a good solution. However, neither Google Calendar or Apple seem to have a intuitive way to send invitations to a shared calendar and have them automatically accepted.
My simple question is:

How do I send invitations from Outlook (or any other client) to my Apple Family Calendar?

Comment: Why do yo need to send an invite to the shared calendar? Can't you just add the event to the shared calendar directly?

Comment: For work-related travel and meetings, i'd like to send an invite to the family calendar to notify my spouse and children. So the source is my work calendar that resides in Exchange/Outlook.